# Facebook , when user token expired ,Real-time Updates will stop the update this user's new data to the server？？

Tags: facebook, real-time

Facebook api question

user add my app and auth, or page add the app as a tab, i use Real-time updates subscribe  changes in data in Facebook,if the token for the user or page is expired,the  Real-time Updates will stop the update this user's new data  to the server？？

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, fb sends real time updates even for users with invalid/expired tokens. Not sure if for all users but definitely for some.